# PHP Datetime: Get date based on month, week of year and week day

Tags: php, datetime

I have a three parameters based on which I want to get the exact date. I have following parameters:

```
Month : integer (01-12) |
Week of month : integer (01-05) |
Day of week : (Sunday-Saturday)
```

I have three parameters above that I want to fetch the date.

For example:

Suppose I have `01 as month 01` as week and day of week as Friday then it should return `03-01-2014`

Assumption: Any inputs will be for future dates only.

Comment: Can you explain how the first month 01 and first week 01 and Friday equals 03-01-2014, that bit is very confusing

Comment: on this basis how will you grab YEAR from these parameters ?

Comment: I was very confused by your result until I remembered that standard American date notation is different from the rest of the world. You should clarify (for American answerers) that your date notation is DD-MM-YYYY (not MM-DD-YYYY).

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @all **mind-reader mode:** presumably OP is only looking up to 1 year ahead.  Regarding format - it's irrelevant, if you walk through it: *The nearest Friday in the first week of the next January falls on the 3rd* - lack of research effort aside, it's actually a trickier question than it might at first seem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use strtotime. Requires day of week and month to be written out (1 Friday January 2013), so I am converting month number into name. I am assuming day of week is already "Friday".

```
function calcDate($day,$week,$month)
{
  $thisYear = date("Y");

  $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10)); //http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/php-month-number-to-month-name-the-easy-way/
  $query = $week." ".$day." ".$monthName;
  $outDate = strtotime($query." ".$thisYear));

  if (outDate < time())
  {
    $outDate = strtotime($query." ".($thisYear+1));
  }
  return date('d-m-Y', $outDate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this can be expanded upon:

```
$month = 'January';
$week = 0;
$day = 'friday';
$year = date("Y") + 1;

$d = new DateTime();
$d->modify("first {$day} of {$month} {$year} +{$week} week");
echo $d->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: +1 this had crossed my mind - I don't know who contributed to the PHP date/string parsing algorithm but they are legends in my eyes because it is *actually* magical!

Comment: @Emissary, I was just reading through the manual page on it and yes it truely is awesome :) [`relative time formats`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)